# Log Files - A command to search for gaps of over 2 minutes in logs

Tags: grep, scripting, logs, search, timestamps

Wondering if someone can help with a query I have re: log files?
I am looking to run a command that will search through a log file and look for sections of that log file where there are no updates for 2 mins.

The log generally updates every second, multiple updates. Ive noticed that sometimes nothing is written to the log for up to 2 mins.

Is there a script of a command I can run that will look for these 2 mins periods of nothing being output. Log file is huge so trying to manually look for these is not an option

Example:

```
Mar 14 **15:00:00** Xps15 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1892]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Mar 14 **15:02:00** Xps15 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1892]: (II) event8
```

Expected behavior (Multiple updates every second:

```
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 gnome-shell[2048]: Removing a network device that was not added
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 NetworkManager[923]: <warn>  [1615736460.0861] sup-iface[fc7990f46420f6bc,7,wlp0s20f3]: call-p2p-cancel: failed with P2P cancel failed
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1892]: (II) config/udev: removing device PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1892]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1892]: (II) event8  - PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: device removed
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1892]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1892]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:72
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: With awk, use the `split()` function to get minutes and seconds from the third field and calculate the difference between the current line and the last line. You may also be successful with a non-awk shell script using `date +%s -d ...`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any built in command that does that. But since they are just text files so you could use `awk`'s functions:

`mktime()` will turn a date into a timestamp. I added *1970 01* to avoid getting false positives when the day changes, although that is not a perfect solution, it will still fail on some month changes. You could pass the actual year and month of the log being handled.

The script keeps the last line and its timestamp and compares it with the current one. When the difference is greater than 120 (2 seconds) the script prints the previous and current line.

```
BEGIN {prev_time=-1;prev_line=""}
{
curr_time = mktime("1970 01 " $2 " " gensub(":"," ","g",$3))
if (prev_line && curr_time - prev_time > 120) {print prev_line"\n"$0}
prev_time = curr_time
prev_line = $0
}
```

You then pipe the log to awk, using this script. I didn't think much about optimization, this is a basic solution you can work on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky solution that works on GNU awk 4.1.3 onwards.  Has the year hardcoded in, as the log file doesn't tell us the year.

```
$ cat data
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 gnome-shell[2048]: Removing a network device that was not added
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 NetworkManager[923]: <warn>  [1615736460.0861] sup-iface[fc7990f46420f6bc,7,wlp0s20f3]: call-p2p-cancel: failed with P2P cancel failed
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1892]: (II) config/udev: removing device PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:42:00 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:43:59 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:44:00 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:46:00 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:48:01 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:49:01 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:49:31 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
$ cat myscript.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{ month=(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1)-1)/3+1;
  timestamp=sprintf("%s %02d %02d %s %s %s",2021,month,$2,substr($3,0,2),substr($3,4,2),substr($3,7,2))
  secs=mktime(timestamp)
  if(secs > last + 119 && last) {
   print substr($0,0,6),"**"substr($0,8,8)"**",substr($0,17)
  } else {
   print $0
  }
  last=secs
}
$ ./myscript.awk <data
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 gnome-shell[2048]: Removing a network device that was not added
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 NetworkManager[923]: <warn>  [1615736460.0861] sup-iface[fc7990f46420f6bc,7,wlp0s20f3]: call-p2p-cancel: failed with P2P cancel failed
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1892]: (II) config/udev: removing device PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse
Mar 14 15:41:00 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:42:00 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:43:59 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:44:00 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 **15:46:00** Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 **15:48:01** Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:49:01 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
Mar 14 15:49:31 Xps15 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
$
```

Comment: Eduardo covers it far more elegantly, so I'll leave mine here as an unnecessarily long version :-)